# Некоторые кнопки пульта функционируют, но не посылают KeyEvent

Tags: android, android-sdk

Некоторые кнопки пульта ( Android Box ) функционируют, но не посылают KeyEvent. Как поставить на них dispatchKeyEvent если я от них не получаю KeyEvent ?

Comment: Android Studio - среда разработки, она ничего не посылает и не получает в плане кнопок

Comment: Согласен, кажется я не ясно раскрыл вопрос. Я подключился к Android Box и получаю каждое нажатие мотодом dispatchKeyEvent и ставлю какой то функционал, но есть пара кнопок с которых я вообще ничего получаю, хотя некоторых из них вполне нормально функционируют.